# R wrangling data: Summarizing and cleaning data (landcover and river quality)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

As you can see from the screenshot below, this is my MCI_dataframe. I am trying to summarise the information so that for Auckland I have 1 value for MCI and 1 value for TaxaRichness for the Forest category, Cropland category, and Urban category for the year 2008

Essentially I need to average these MCI and taxa richness values based on the conditions above. I know that I need to group_by and summarise but I don't know how to lay my code out
[This is an image of my data frame I need to wrangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwQew.png)

Comment: Difficult to say without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but perhaps 
`data %>% filter(year == "2008") %>% group_by(regions_nz, cover_type) %>% summarise(MCI = mean(MCI), TaxaRichness = mean(TaxaRichness))`?

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot ! You have helped me solve my problem !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(regions_nz, year, cover_type) %>% 
  summarise(mean_MCI = mean(MCI), mean_TaxaRichness = mean(TaxaRichness))
```

```
  regions_nz  year cover_type                            mean_MCI mean_TaxaRichness
  <chr>      <int> <chr>                                    <dbl>             <dbl>
1 auckland    2008 Cropland                                  92.3              23.3
2 auckland    2008 Forest                                   114.               31.2
3 auckland    2008 Urban/bare/lightly-vegetated_surfaces     74.5              20.5
```

```
structure(list(regions_nz = c("auckland", "auckland", "auckland", 
"auckland", "auckland", "auckland", "auckland", "auckland", "auckland", 
"auckland", "auckland", "auckland", "auckland", "auckland", "auckland", 
"auckland", "auckland", "auckland", "auckland"), year = c(2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L
), cover_type = c("Cropland", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", 
"Cropland", "Cropland", "Urban/bare/lightly-vegetated_surfaces", 
"Urban/bare/lightly-vegetated_surfaces", "Cropland", "Cropland", 
"Cropland", "Cropland", "Cropland", "Cropland", "Cropland", "Cropland", 
"Forest", "Cropland"), MCI = c(98, 107, 85, 121, 127, 62, 123, 
86, 63, 52, 56, 74, 114, 113, 124, 98, 83, 128, 111), TaxaRichness = c(35L, 
36L, 24L, 39L, 38L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 22L, 20L, 17L, 27L, 32L, 24L, 
19L, 24L, 23L, 19L, 19L), Agency = c("ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", 
"ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", 
"ac", "ac", "ac", "ac"), LawaSitelD = c("arc-00141", "arc-00001", 
"arc-00013", "arc-00128", "arc-00148", "arc-00024", "arc-00146", 
"arc-00116", "arc-00010", "arc-00016", "arc-00021", "arc-00113", 
"arc-00115", "arc-00135", "lawa-102726", "arc-00025", "arc-00114", 
"arc-00132", "arc-00134"), SiteID = c(1043828L, 44618L, 7925L, 
44460L, 44470L, 7527L, 7526L, 7722L, 8177L, 8241L, 1043825L, 
6606L, 6852L, 7314L, 6847L, 8553L, 8407L, 45605L, 7315L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```